# Different space between letters in different editors

Tags: fonts

I noticed that on some editors, spaces between characters are not the same.

Here is an example white libreoffice

[image]

You can notice that, between each block of 4 or 5 `i`, the space is bigger.

I tested the same example on google doc and spaces seems to be the same :

[image]

I told me It was a libreoffice bug, but I tried on another online editor (onlyoffice) and I can reproduce this behavior

[image]

So the question is : It's a bug or a feature ? And, how can I disable that ?

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: I tried with differents font (on theses screenshots, it's arial)

Comment: are those smaller `i`'s  in one editor than the other?  btw you probably know this but courier is a fixed width font so if you wanted that you could use that. Also, an interest test would be to see if courier even takes up different space, then it looks very much like it'd be the size of the font perhaps. Maybe it reners e.g. size 10 differently.

Comment: All those test was made with the same font and same size. With a fixed font (like courier) the spacing looks working (because space is very large and Icould see a little difference). I want use those editors for writing a report, for obvious reasons, I cannot use monospaced or fixed width font.

Comment: Does this still happen if you zoom in? How about if you save the document as a PDF file, is it still there in the PDF file then? Or if you print the document on paper? Most likely (I would guess), it’s just the screen hinting that isn’t very good in those apps, so some letters that are supposed to be between two pixels get moved to one side or the other.

Comment: On printed (PDF) documents, everything work good. How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different subpixel antialiasing routines causes fonts to appear to shift. Theres little you can do about this. Different rendering engines just work out differently.

Your comment about the problem dissapearing in PDF seems to confirm this line of thinking. You might get different results by hinting the fonts differently. Plese note even the browser shows the problem in form of a constantly shifting intensity wave. Libre office just wants to hint the stem to a full pixel width. Forcing it to eventually skip a pixel.